# "Merge" subsequent counter-based commands

Tags: numbering, expl3, counters, expansion

I'm trying to implement two simple paragraph numbering commands `\verse` and `\subverse`.
When a `\verse` command is followed by a `\subverse` (irrespective of spaces and new lines), only the subverse counter should be displayed.

Here are a few examples:

[image: Examples of \verse and \subverse]

I managed to produce the following code that seems to work:

```tex
\int_new:N \g__test_peek_int

\cs_new:Nn \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n
  {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_space_token
      { \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n {#1} }
      {
        \peek_meaning_remove:NTF \par
          { \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n {#1} }
          {
            \int_gincr:N \g__test_peek_int
            \cs_gset:cn
              { __test_peek_ \int_use:N \g__test_peek_int : }
              {#1}
            \use:c
              { __test_peek_ \int_use:N \g__test_peek_int : }
          }
      }
  }

\newcounter { verse }
\newcounter { subverse } [ verse ]

\DeclareDocumentCommand \theverse {}
  { \arabic { verse } }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \thesubverse {}
  { \theverse . \arabic { subverse } }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \verse {}
  {
    \refstepcounter { verse }
    \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n
      {
        \peek_meaning:NF \subverse
          {
            \textbf { \theverse . ~ }
            \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n {}
          }
      }
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \subverse {}
  {
    \refstepcounter { subverse }
    \textbf { \thesubverse . ~ }
    \__test_peek_remove_spaces_and_pars:n {}
  }
```

This is probably far from the best approach.

One problem however is that I would like to support `\labels`. More specifically, the construct `\verse \label{mylabel} \par \subverse text` should produce `1.1. text`. But, the `\label` command "breaks" the peek loop and the `\verse`/`\subverse` are not "merged".

Is there a (preferably LaTeX3 based) solution to this problem, maybe by expanding tokens after the `\verse` command until either a `\subverse` or another non-space non-`\par` token is found?

Comment: Beware of `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. You risk, like in this case, to overwrite an existing command, with possible disaster coming next. Maybe you don't need the `verse` environment, but what if you `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\box}{m}{...}`?